# Does $\det(A)\det(B) = \det(A)\det(C) \implies \det(B) = \det(C)$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, determinant

It is proven that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices of order n.

> If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are square matrices of the same size and
>   $\det(AB) = \det(AC)$, then $\det(B) = \det(C)$. True/False?

I presume that the above is true because 
$$\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) \tag 1$$
$$\det(AC) = \det(A)\det(C) \tag 2$$

Equate both $\det(AB) = \det(AC)$, 
$$\det(A)\det(B) = \det(A)\det(C) \implies \det(B) = \det(C) \tag 3$$

However, this is not true in the following example:

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $C = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Then $\det(AB) = 0 = \det(AC)$, but $\det(B) = 1 ≠ 0 = \det(C) = 0$.

**Why is that so?**

Comment: It is true only if $det(A)\ne0$

Comment: The matrices here are the "red herring" (misleading lead), really it is just about numbers. $x\cdot 0=y\cdot 0$ does not imply $x=y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you can't divide by $0$. For instance, $0\times1=0\times2$, but $1\neq2$.

Answer (score 8):

Hint:

from $ax=ay$ we can deduce $x=y$ only if $a\ne 0$.

What does this implies for the matrix $A$?